# ./gradlew failed in React Native 0.68 (Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, upgrade

After updating to React Native 0.68, I got this error when executing ./gradlew :

```sh
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/username/path/projectname/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MacOS, you just need to install the Java Development Kit recommended by React Native

```sh
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask zulu11
```

I guess you need to do `choco install -y nodejs-lts openjdk11` on Windows by I haven't tested it.

*Source: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#installing-dependencies*